# Parameter constraints

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks, constraints

I am using the Rhino Mocks framework.
I referenced the Rhinomocks dll and everything worked fine..
but when I was trying to use the LastCall.Constraints(Is.Anything())
it says: Error The name 'Is' does not exist in the current context
The same happens with Text and List constraints..
any help??

Answer (score 3):

Are you

```
using Rhino.Mocks.Constraints;
```

?

The ´Is´ class is defined in the ´Constraints´ namespace which must be referenced explicitly in order to use the class.

Comment: thx a loot...it worked :)
i thought using Rhino.Mocks was enough!!

Comment: Yes, the Is class is in a separate namespace. If this solved your problem, could you please mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the RhinoMocks framework, but I found some code that might help you. This is [a file from the SVN of castleproject.org](https://svn.castleproject.org/svn/castle/trunk/MonoRail/Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Tests/Services/EmailTemplateServiceTestCase.cs) that uses it, you might want to compare your approach with theirs.